# go test prints output only after tests have finished

Tags: go, ginkgo

I noticed that `go test` seems to print to stdout after tests have finished.

I'm not sure if this is `go test`'s issue, or because I am using [ginkgo](https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/) as well.

Does anyone know how to make it print output as the tests run?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205419/how-do-you-print-in-a-go-test-using-the-testing-package

Answer (score 2):

Use the verbose flag on go test to see output of log or print statements as tests are run.

```
go test -v
```