# Logging in Golang test case

Tags: go, testing

I have this:

```
package utils_test

import (
    "huru/utils"
    "testing"
)

func TestSetFields(t *testing.T) {

    t.Log("dest.Foo")

    src := struct{}{}
    dest := struct{}{}
    utils.SetFields(&src, &dest)

    t.Log("dest.Foo", dest)
}
```

and I run this command:

```
go test -run TestSetFields ./src/huru/utils/utils_test.go
```

all I see this output:

```
ok      command-line-arguments  (cached)
```

I can't get any logging output, I tried log.Println and t.Log, to no avail.

Comment: "For tests, the text will be printed only if the test fails or the -test.v flag is set." https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Log

Comment: It's also cached, so set the environment variable GOCACHE to off

Comment: @poy like this `export GOCACHE="off"`?

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman correct

Comment: @poy why this then lol https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038556/setting-gocache-on-put-a-bunch-of-files-in-the-on-directory-lol

Comment: Because only off is valid. The reverse is not.

Comment: well using "on" clearly means something - it tells Golang where to put the cache, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
go test -v -run TestSetFields ./src/huru/utils/utils_test.go
```

Here is the answer
[How do you print in a Go test using the "testing" package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205419/how-do-you-print-in-a-go-test-using-the-testing-package)

Comment: thanks so you have to point to the full file path? I was hoping you could just run `go test -v -run TestSetFields` from the base of your project, oh well.

Comment: perhaps mention the `-test.v` flag?